# How to know if the current element is selected

Tags: jquery

The idea is to go through all input fields and when `$(this)` has the radio type, check if it's selected, if it is save its value.

I know there are other ways to get the value of the selected radio button but Im already going through all inputs and doing something similar.

I've tried to check the attribute selected, `$(this).attr('selected')` without any luck... and I have no idea of how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to save it's value to?

Comment: `selected` is not an attribute a radio will ever have, but `checked` is. You can use `.is` and the pseudo selector `:checked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For radio button, you should use `checked`.

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following:

```
$(this).is(':radio:checked');
```

Comment: Should be is(':radio:checked')

Answer (score 1):

To check selection of radio button use:

`.prop('checked');`

```
$('input').each(function() {
   if( this.type == 'radio' ) {
     console.log( $(this).prop('checked') );  // or, this.checked
                                              // or, $(this).is(':checked')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete bins for above query. please check demo link given below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp76

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Check Selected" />
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 1"/>
    Checkbox1 
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 2"/>
    Checkbox2 
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 3"/>
    Checkbox3 
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 4"/>
    Checkbox4 
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 5"/>
    Checkbox5 
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="rd" value="Radio 1"/>
    Radio-1 
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rd" value="Radio 2"/>
    Radio-2 
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rd" value="Radio 3"/>
    Radio-3 
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rd" value="Radio 4"/>
    Radio-4 
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rd" value="Radio 5"/>
    Radio-5 
  </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var SelChk = "Selected Checkbox Values: ";
        var SelRad = "Selected Radio Value:";

        $("input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checkbox:checked")) {
                SelChk += $(this).val().trim() + ", ";
            }
            if ($(this).is(":radio:checked")) {
                SelRad += $(this).val().trim();
            }
        });

        if (SelChk.substr(-2) == ", ") SelChk = SelChk.substr(0, SelChk.length - 2);

        alert(SelChk + "\n" + SelRad);
    });

});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp76

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the examples here http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

HTML radio inputs don't hace selected attribute, but checked, like described [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/radio)
Also, from jQuery 1.6 you should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get and set that kind of boolean conditions: $(this).prop("checked") will return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='radio']).each(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
      // perform your operation
    }
});
```